# Mapping Wavefront .obj texture vertex on OpenGL

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping, .obj, wavefront

An artist gave me all 3D models for me exporting to .obj and .mtl in order that I can render it using OpenGL.

But I can't figure out why the texture vertex are greater than 1 and sometimes negative.
Take a look at this example:

```
(...)
vn -0.000717425 0.00106739 -0.00991695
vn 3.49779e-09 -5.22866e-09 -0.01
vn -0.00142294 0.00211706 -0.00966919
vn -0.00831486 -0.00555545 0
vt 5.82424 -20.091
vt 6.97527 -20.1873
vt 5.81848 -20.1618
vt -7.48189 8.29159
(...)
```

He sent me all textures on TGA format, which I am loading it correctly, but I am not being able to map these `vt`s to a correct OpenGL texture vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I can't figure out why the texture vertex are greater than 1 and sometimes negative.

Texture coordinates outside the `[0..1]` range indicate texture repetition.

Given a 1D texture `ABCD`:

```
   -1    0    1    2
....|ABCD|ABCD|ABCD|....
```

Make sure `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` are set to `GL_REPEAT`.

Comment: I got it. But does the negative numbers make any sense? I have the 'GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S' and 'GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T' set, and now it is working for some textures, but not all of them. Guess I need to figure out how to set another property for negative numbers to work now.

Comment: Negative numbers just wrap in the other direction.  See my edit.